# difference between Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost nuget packages

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, owin

I want to host my `WebApi` project in `IIS` and Self-Host context. In my researches, For `IIS` hosting, I found these two packages:

1- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost  ([src](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost/))

> This package contains everything you need to host ASP.NET Web API on
>   IIS

2- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb ([src](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/))

> OWIN server that enables OWIN-based applications to run on IIS using
>   the ASP.NET request pipeline.

My `WebApi` app can be loaded in IIS with both of them. So the question is what is the difference between these two packages and in which condition I should use them.

P.S.
I get some error when hosting with second package in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This package *Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb* is required if you want to host Web.API on a OWIN [pipeline](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) and you are hosting this pipeline on IIS (you don't need this for self-hosting, for example inside a console app).

The other one is required for "classic" Web.API [hosting](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and has nothing to do with OWIN itself.

I guess you want to run OWIN (because you're self hosting too), so you need the second one.

BTW, the OWIN equivalent of *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost* is *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin*.

Comment: "BTW, the OWIN equivalent of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin." What is the difference between these two packages?